# Target element with certain data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't work out how to target an element with a certain data attribute.
In my case the `a` with `class="zoom-image"` and `data-order-item-id="<?=$order_item_id ?>"`.

The html/php is below ( this code is in a loop and will repeat many times):

```
 <div class="history_image">
     <img src="<?= $order_image ?>" alt="Image of product">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="zoom-image" data-order-item-id="<?=$order_item_id ?>">
         <span class="trans_top"><?= lang('view')?></span>
         <span class="trans_bottom"></span>
     </a>
      <div id="zoom-image-holder-<?=$order_item_id ?>" class="zoom-image-holder hidden">
          <img src="<?= $order_image_full?>" alt="Image of product">
      </div>
 </div>
```

My js works for one, but when you have more than one it apply to all. I need to target only the `a` that is hovered and use the `data-order-item-id="<?=$order_item_id ?>` as a point of reference ( I think ).
What the js does is basically add a fade, and animates some links:

```
function hoverFadeIn()
{
    zoomId = $(this).data("order-item-id");
    var holderHeight = ($(this).height());
    var transRatio = 0.7;
    transValue = holderHeight * transRatio;
    transValueTop = transValue+'px';
    transValueBottom = '-'+transValue+'px';

    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
        }, 300, function() {
        // Animation complete.
     });
     $('.trans_top').animate({
        transform: 'translateY('+transValueTop+')'
      });
     $('.trans_bottom').animate({
        transform: 'translateY('+transValueBottom+')'
      });
}
function hoverFadeOut()
{
    $(this).animate({
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        }, 300, function() {
        // Animation complete.
     });
     $('.trans_top').animate({
        transform: 'translateY(0px)'
      });
     $('.trans_bottom').animate({
        transform: 'translateY(0px)'
      });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   var zoomId = 0 ;
   $(".zoom-image").click(function() {
        zoomId = $(this).data("order-item-id");
        $("#zoom-image-holder-"+zoomId).dialog(opt).dialog("open");
    });
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").live("click", function() {  $("#zoom-image-holder-"+zoomId).dialog("close"); } );
    $(".zoom-image").hoverIntent( hoverFadeIn, hoverFadeOut );     
});
```

I'm sure its the `$(this).animate` needs to change and also only apply

```
$('.trans_top').animate({
        transform: 'translateY('+transValueTop+')'
      });
     $('.trans_bottom').animate({
        transform: 'translateY('+transValueBottom+')'
      });
```

to the current div being hovered

Comment: are you checking just the existence of `data-order-item-id` attribute or a particular value for the attribute

Comment: I think i need to check for a particular value.
I get and set the data value with  "zoomId = $(this).data("order-item-id");"
so i need to then apply the functions hoverFadeIn and hoverFadeOut to this data-order-item-id with that "zoomid"

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[data-order-item-id].zoom-image").click(function () {
    zoomId = $(this).data("order-item-id");
    $("#zoom-image-holder-" + zoomId).dialog(opt).dialog("open");
});
```

This will target only `a` with class `.zoom-image` and that contains `data-order-item-id`

Comment: Thank you for this.
The click function is ok and works how i would like
as this gets zoomId = $(this).data("order-item-id"); 
My problem is within the 
$(".zoom-image").hoverIntent( hoverFadeIn, hoverFadeOut );   and these functions being applied to all add the a with .zoom.